# Check secure OpenID redirect?

Tags: python, openid

The process for openid login for my server redirects to google, for example, then google redirects back to a page with parameters in the parameter string.  how do I verify this really came from google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameters probably contain an OpenID assertion (or an error).  You can verify the assertion by following the instructions in the OpenID spec:

http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#verification

You probably don't want to do all the work yourself, though, since it's a bit complicated.  The Janrain OpenID library for python can simplify the process somewhat:

http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled

To make things even simpler, find an OpenID plugin for your web framework.  Here is one for [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/):

http://packages.python.org/Flask-OpenID/